# Error: GGPlot 2 Geom Segment Must be Continuous (X is Numeric not Continuous)

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am trying to make a lollipop chart in ggplot with the following dataset (below) where Delta is Numeric and City is Character. Below is my code. I am getting the following error:

```
 Discrete Value provided to Continous Scale.
```

Here my code:

```
p <- ggplot(city_delta, aes(x=City, y=Delta)) +
     geom_segment( aes(x=City, xend=City, y=0, yend=Delta ), 
     color = ifelse(city_delta$City %in% c("Denver","Baltimore"), "orange", "grey"), 
     size=ifelse(city_delta$City %in% c("Denver","Baltimore"), 1.3, 0.7) )
```

For reference I am trying to make something like this:

[image]

https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/304-highlight-a-group-in-lollipop/

```
structure(list(City = c("Wichita", "Kansas City", "Syracuse", 
"St. Louis", "Denver", "Memphis", "Milwaukee", "Oklahoma City", 
"Pittsburgh", "Dayton", "Columbus", "Charleston", "Chicago", 
"Baltimore"), Delta = c("0.85", "0.85", "0.83", "0.83", "0.81", 
"0.79", "0.78", "0.76", "0.74", "0.64", "0.56", "0.55", "0.52", 
"0.4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L), .Names = c("City", 
"Delta"))
```

[image]

Comment: where did you get the dataset? If it's not a default one please share it with `dput()` so we can try out your code with your dataset (output looks a bit ugly though it helps)

Comment: @mischva11 I have updated it with the data: 
structure(list(City = c("Wichita", "Kansas City", "Syracuse", 
"St. Louis", "Denver", "Memphis", "Milwaukee", "Oklahoma City", 
"Pittsburgh", "Dayton", "Columbus", "Charleston", "Chicago", 
"Baltimore"), Delta = c("0.85", "0.85", "0.83", "0.83", "0.81", 
"0.79", "0.78", "0.76", "0.74", "0.64", "0.56", "0.55", "0.52", 
"0.4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L), .Names = c("City", 
"Delta"))

Comment: `Delta` is of type character. Call `city_delta[] <- lapply(city_delta, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)` before you plot.

Answer (score 0):

As markus stated in his comment:

```
city_delta[] <- lapply(city_delta, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)

p <- ggplot(city_delta, aes(x=City, y=Delta)) +
      geom_segment( aes(x=City, xend=City, y=0, yend=Delta ), 
                    color = ifelse(city_delta$City %in% c("Denver","Baltimore"), "orange", "grey"), 
                    size=ifelse(city_delta$City %in% c("Denver","Baltimore"), 1.3, 0.7) ) +
      geom_point( color=ifelse(city_delta$City %in% c("Denver","Baltimore"), "orange", "grey"), size=ifelse(city_delta$City %in% c("Denver","Baltimore"), 5, 2) ) +
      theme_light() +
      coord_flip() +
      theme(
        legend.position="none",
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
      ) +
      xlab("") +
      ylab("Value of Y")
```